# Download images to Google Cloud Storage using geemap.download_ee_image_tiles

Tags: google-earth-engine, vector-grid, download, geemap, google-cloud

Few days ago I saw on a Linkedin post that [download_ee_image_tiles](https://geemap.org/notebooks/136_download_parallel/) option was added to geemap. I was trying to use it with image I had and a fishnet that I have created before. However, I am not sure where the data is uploaded to, and if it can be uploaded to GCS (google cloud storage). This is how I tried to use the download_ee_image_tiles:

```
#I know that image collection has more than 1 image
img=img_coll.median()

#fct is geopandas fishnet (polygon per cell) converted into featureCollection

geemap.download_ee_image_tiles_parallel(img, fct, out_dir='path/on/google/cloud/storage, scale=10, crs="EPSG:4326")
```

This runs and returns nothing. Also, nothing was downloaded to my GCS. I was trying to upload it to google cloud storage path, but then I realized that I don't know if it works with GCS, as there is also specific function to upload to GCS (ee.batch.Export.image.toCloudStorage).

**My end goal is to be able to upload images to GCS, using the geemap.download_ee_images_tiles_parallel, and if it's impossible , to understand to which destiantions the data can be downloaded.**

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should be able to set `out_dir` to `gs://bucket-name/path/on/gcs` or possibly `/vsigs/bucket-name/path/on/gcs` that way GDAL will understand the destination is not a local file. Otherwise I believe it is writing the files to that path on the local filesystem.

Explanation:

- You are calling `geemap.download_ee_image_tiles_parallel`.
- Which is calling `geemap.download_ee_image` ([here](https://github.com/gee-community/geemap/blob/master/geemap/common.py#L12084)).
- Which is calling `geedim.download.BaseImage.download` ([here](https://github.com/gee-community/geemap/blob/master/geemap/common.py#L11880)).
- Which is calling `rasrerio.open` ([here](https://github.com/leftfield-geospatial/geedim/blob/main/geedim/download.py#L937)).
- Which in turn is using GDAL.

After tracing through all that, we know we need the `out_dir` to be a value that rasterio / GDAL will understand. Which leads to [this rasterio issue](https://github.com/rasterio/rasterio/issues/991) which discusses `gs://` and the [GDAL Docs](https://gdal.org/user/virtual_file_systems.html#vsigs) explaining `/vsigs/` usage. You may need to check those docs for specific connection settings.